# Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, typescript

The method **foo** gets some HTML elements using JQuery and do some stuff in a loop with them.
Another method **bar**, returns some value based on the input from method **foo**.
In the loop, ***this*** means a particular HTML element of the list obviously.

Out of the loop, ***this*** represents the current class. I can call any method in this class. But in the loop it represents the HTML element.

My question is, how can I call bar() without using ***this***

```
    foo(source: Source[] | undefined){
       let codeLines: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $('.source');
       codeLines.each(function (index) {
           this.bar(this.innerHTML); //this line throws the **error**.
       });
    }

    bar(innerHTML: string){
       return 0;
    }
```

The **error** is,

```
TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the outer this in a variable.

```
foo(source: Source[] | undefined){
    let thisCapture = this;
   let codeLines: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $('.source');
   codeLines.each(function (index) {
       thisCapture.bar(this.innerHTML); //this line throws the **error**.
   });
}

bar(innerHTML: string){
   return 0;
}
```